# Datatables Download Excel currency symbol is displaying after the price?

Tags: datatables

I'm using the data tables to download Excel. Once I downloaded the Excel the currency symbol is coming after the price. How to set the field type as the currency format.

Tried with the render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$' )

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] and make sure to clarify what locale you are using. Also you should explicitly show us what you are getting now and you should explicitly show us what you want instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(123456.789);`. See [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat). Use this in a DataTables column renderer to convert `123456.789` to `$123,456.79`